# What is Ganache currency symbol

Tags: blockchain, metamask, ganache

I am trying to connect Ganache local network to Metamask, using official documentation.

However, it won't let connect without filling the `currency symbol` of the network.

What would it be?

Answer (score 1):

ETH should work (assuming you have enough balance in your Ganache test accounts)